# Check if an agent pool is mapped to a collection project in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps Server, an agent pool is scoped to the entire server, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser).
However, only projects that "imported" the agent pool to the project can actually use it. My question is - is there a way to check using REST API whether or not a project is authorized to use a specific agent pool?

I know there's this REST method:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=6.0
```

Which gives you a list of all agnet pools in the collection.
(By the way - if agent pools are scoped to the entire server, why is it this call scoped to a specific collection?)
But in the response there is no way to know to which projects the agent pool is mapped to.

Comment: There's another API to query the agent queues of a project, the queue has the wool id. Pools are collection scoped, not server scoped if I remember correctly, but on Azure DevOps Cloud there is always just 1 collection.

Comment: @jessehouwing, what is the difference between pools and queues?

Comment: Queue is the name of a Pool at project level. I think the UI now calls both pool, but when first introduced they were named differently at different levels

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/get

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get-agent-pools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this API to check if the agent pool bind to specific Azure DevOps project.
Actually the queueName == agentPoolName

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/queues?queueNames={queueNames}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

[API Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/get-agent-queues-by-names?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Answer (score 0):

> Check if an agent pool is mapped to a collection project in Azure DevOps?

I am afraid there is no such way to check if an agent pool is mapped to a collection project in Azure DevOps.

According to the document [Agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser):

> pools are **scoped to the entire organization**; so you can share the
> agent machines across projects. In Azure DevOps **Server**, agent pools
> are scoped to the entire server; so you can share the agent machines
> across projects and collections.

This means that the entire pipeline in the organization or Azure DevOps Server can access this agent pool.

in other words, the agent pool is mapped to all projects in Azure DevOps services and all collections for the Azure devops server.

Comment: Actually @jessehouwing answered in the comment above: the mapping between an agent pool and a project is called an "Agent queue" and apparently there is a  REST API call to get the agent queues for a project..

Comment: @YoavKlein, The REST API about Agent queue only returns the agents contained in your agent pool, and does not return the projects mapped by each agent

Comment: The call itself is scoped to a project... (i.e. http://your-org/collection/project/_apis/...)